# If we have a bean (i.e an object) inside a java bean rather than primitive type the how we map internal bean's property using OpenCSV

Tags: java, hibernate, csv, opencsv

If we have a bean (i.e an object) inside a java bean rather than primitive type the how we map internal bean's property using OpenCSV

for example flightId of flight
BEANS
SCHEDULE(scheduleId,flight,route,and other fields)

Flight(flightid,other fields)

Route(routeId,otherfields)

```
package temp.csv;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.model.Schedule;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.ColumnPositionMappingStrategy;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;

public class Abcd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CsvToBean<Schedule> csv = new CsvToBean<Schedule>();
        String csvFilename = "D:\\Travel_Portal\\Schedule\\SCHEDULE_4-10_12.26.54.csv ";
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Schedule> strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Schedule>();
        strat.setType(Schedule.class);
        String[] columns = new String[] { "scheduleId", "flight.flightId",
                "route.routeId", "availSourceDest", "availSourceVia",
                "availViaDest", "fareSourceDest", "fareSourceVia",
                "fareViaDest" };
        // the fields to bind do in your JavaBean
        strat.setColumnMapping(columns);

        CSVReader csvReader = null;
        try {
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Schedule> list = csv.parse(strat, csvReader);
        try {
            for (Object object : list) {
                Schedule schedule = (Schedule) object;
                System.out.println(schedule.getScheduleId() + " "
                        + schedule.getFlight() + schedule.getRoute());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

//This is CSV file

```
"SID121","AI101","RID101",100,-1,-1,5000,-1,-1,"2013-10-20 11:30:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","0000-00-00 00:00:00","2013-10-20 12:00:00","DID105"
```

//Schedule Class

```
    public class Schedule implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String scheduleId;
    private Flight flight;
    private Deal deal;
    private Route route;
    private int availSourceDest;
    private Integer availSourceVia;
    private Integer availViaDest;
    private double fareSourceDest;
    private double fareSourceVia;
    private double fareViaDest;
    private Date sourceTime;
    private Date viaArrTime;
    private Date viaDeptTime;
    private Date destTime;
    //getter and setter
}
//Flight
    public class Flight implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String flightId;
    private Provider provider;
    private int capacity;
    //getter setter

}
```

Comment: I think we'll need the Schedule class to help.

Comment: please find the edited question thanks

Comment: The Flight class also contains an Object, Provider.  If Provider is similarly flat in structure then they could all just become more columns.  I'm not sure how to do it with OpenCSV as I use jackson for CSV parsing.  In jackson you could create a custom serialiser/deserialiser for those fields, or create getters/setters for the flight object within the Schedule class and mark them as serializable.